# Tailing Apache Logs - What is the number after the IP address

Tags: networking, server, apache2, logging, tail

I am tailing the Apache error logs on my VPS so I can watch the traffic go by. I have been under a DOS attack, or a heavy port scan. I have the apache logging level set to `LogLevel Warn`. What does the number after the IP stand for?  In my example case `[client 199.30.24.133:63960]`, what does the **63960** stand for? Each line has a different number after the IP. I thought it might be the port number, but even my own HTTP traffic has these random numbers.

`[Tue Feb 06 19:29:36.648185 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21105] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 199.30.24.133:63960] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted`

I have read the Apache docs, but they do not address the numbers after the colon. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: It _is_ the client's port.

Answer (score 0):

This is the client port for sure. To link client port and your service port  use for example [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/).